# SQL ORDER BY with conditional results from another table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a WordPress post table and a postmeta table. For those who aren't familiar with the structure, here they are:

The `wp_postmeta` table:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meta_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| meta_key   | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta_value | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Example data of `wp_postmeta`:

```
+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key            | meta_value  |
+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------+
|   20399 |     267 | youtube_video_id_zh | xdr4lzJ4pYU |
|   20403 |     267 | video_view_count    | 3           |
|   21855 |     278 | video_view_count    | 13          |
|   21858 |     278 | youtube_video_id_zh | 5yS5cmA4-rg |
|   26042 |     354 | video_view_count    | 13          |
|   26138 |     354 | youtube_video_id_zh | iXWMThIohcM |
+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------+
```

The `wp_posts` table: (ID is the post ID)

```
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type                | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| ID                     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| (other fields skipped) |                     |      |     |          |                |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
```

Each WordPress post can have multiple meta rows in `wp_postmeta`. I need to do a `SELECT` on the `wp_posts` table with `ORDER BY` based on the value of `meta_value` but only when `meta_key` is `video_view_count` so that I can get the posts with the highest/lowest view count. I can't use a simple `JOIN` because a `WHERE` condition need to check for other types of `meta_key`.

Is this possible in (My)SQL?

Comment: `JOIN` + `ORDER BY`. Start with just pulling the data from both tables without ordering (i.e. show the value of `video_view_count` for each row in `wp_posts`)

Comment: @RandomSeed I've updated the question a bit. Forgot that I can't use a simple JOIN because a WHERE condition need to check for other types of `meta_key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off we can join onto post meta from wp_posts and select the post data. Note we use group by because of the join.

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM
wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id)
GROUP BY wp_posts.id
```

From here we can only join onto the appropriate postmeta and use that to order:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS video_count FROM
wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'video_view_count')
GROUP BY wp_posts.id
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value
```

(Note the group by is not actually neccessary if meta_keys aren't duplicated per post)

Edit after comments, added exclude on another postmeta:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS video_count 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ex ON (wp_posts.id = ex.post_id  AND wp_ex.meta_key = 'video_duration' AND CAST(wp_ex.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '240')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'video_view_count')
GROUP BY wp_posts.id
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value
```

Comment: A problem: I need to, in the same query, also access other wp_postmeta rows where meta_key isn't video_view_count. Will this work?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 In what way? Can you provide an example output in your question? Joining onto other postmeta rows would be possible but would mean you get the same post appearing more than once in the results (which may be fine depending on what you want).

Comment: I have this bit in the WHERE clause: `AND (( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'video_duration' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '240' ))` which can't happen if I only look for `video_view_count`.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 In that case I would do two joins. One for the order and one for the where. I'll add an example in my answer.